# How to undo “close issue” action on GitHub

Tags: github

On GitHub, I closed an issue by error. Where "by error" means that I closed it because I pressed the wrong button and not because I though that the issue was fixed.

I know it is possible to reopen the issue but I would like to undo the close command in such a way that it is removed from the history. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

The Close and Re-open status of an issue will just remain part of its history.

Accidents happen. So do reviews which necessitate reopening an issue. Do not worry about it. It happens.

Comment: I don't worry, simply I don't like it :-)

Comment: It may look "ugly" but unfortunately, it's unavoidable